# HttpUrlConnection authentication not working

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection

Here's the curl command I'm attempting to replicate:

Below is the curl request.

```
    curl user:password@localhost:8080/foo/bar -d property_one=value_one -d property_two=value_two -d property_three=value_three
```

And here is the code for httpurlconnection

```
    URL thisurl = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/foo");
    String encoding = Base64Encoder.base64Encode("user:password");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) thisurl.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.addRequestProperty("property_one", "value_one");
    connection.addRequestProperty("property_two", "value_two");
    connection.addRequestProperty("property_three", "property_three");
    connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
```

On the connection.getInputStream() line I get a 401 error.  Am I doing the authentication wrong?

Comment: Don't know if this matters but your URL is different.

Comment: Did you try without the `connection.setDoOutput(true);`? A get request does not allow output.

Comment: 1) The cURL request is a `POST` request. Any request with `-d` will be made implicitly a `POST`. 2) The data should be sent in the body of the request as url encoded form parameters, not in the request property. 3) The `Content-Type` header is implicitly set in the cURL request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You should do the same in the Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Here you're setting the method to "GET", which is the same as you used with `curl`.

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Here you are implicitly setting it to "POST", which isn't the same, so you don't have any reason to expect the same result.

Don't do all this authentication by hand. Use `java.net.Authenticator.` That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

`401 error` because off user authentication.It may be possible that you are *not encoding authentication header properly*. use this code it worked for me.you can get detail here [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html)

```
 URL url = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/foo");
 String encoding = org.apache.catalina.util.Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes("UTF-8"));

URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));
```